# Fontify org quote blocks with font-locked markup

Tags: org-mode, fonts, font-lock, quote, markup

I have `org-fontify-quote-and-verse-blocks` set to `t` and `'(org-block ((t (:foreground "#2E8B57"))))` to make quote blocks stand out in a particular color. However, this also means that I cannot get markup like `/emphasis/` or `*bold*` to display properly in such a fontified quote block.

So is there a way to have both of these together? In other words, have fontified quote blocks that display in a particular color and have them display text according to its markup (i.e. `/emphasis/` looks like *emphasis*?

EDIT: On emacs 25.3.1 and org 9.1.3 this now works, though I'm not sure what the change was that allowed this to be so.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that this was removed in source blocks in [this commit](http://orgmode.org/cgit.cgi/org-mode.git/commit/?id=f8b42e8), and presumably the same goes for quote & verse blocks as well.