# Italics not shown in block quotes in orgmode

Tags: org-mode, fonts, faces

In my blockquotes in org-mode, the fontification does not pick up on italics. I have looked at [this question and answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28583/fontify-org-quote-blocks-with-font-locked-markup) that says it was fixed several years ago, but my issue persists.

I have tried using `describe-face` to find the issue but it does not seem to contain any modifications that should affect or hide italics:

```
    Face: org-quote (sample) (customize this face)
    
    Documentation:
    Face for #+BEGIN_QUOTE ... #+END_QUOTE blocks.
    
    Defined in ‘org-faces.el’.

           Family: unspecified
          Foundry: unspecified
            Width: unspecified
           Height: unspecified
           Weight: normal
            Slant: unspecified
       Foreground: #181818
DistantForeground: unspecified
       Background: grey95
        Underline: unspecified
         Overline: unspecified
   Strike-through: unspecified
              Box: unspecified
          Inverse: unspecified
          Stipple: unspecified
             Font: unspecified
          Fontset: unspecified
           Extend: unspecified
          Inherit: unspecified
```

Italics show fine in other text. Here is an example showing the same text italicized, inside and outside a block quote:

[image]

`C-u C-x =` on italicized text gives this:

```
             position: 488528 of 488671 (100%), column: 30
            character: n (displayed as n) (codepoint 110, #o156, #x6e)
              charset: ascii (ASCII (ISO646 IRV))
code point in charset: 0x6E
               script: latin
               syntax: w    which means: word
             category: .:Base, L:Left-to-right (strong), a:ASCII, l:Latin, r:Roman
             to input: type "C-x 8 RET 6e" or "C-x 8 RET LATIN SMALL LETTER N"
          buffer code: #x6E
            file code: #x6E (encoded by coding system utf-8-unix)
              display: by this font (glyph code)
    mac-ct:-*-Libre Baskerville-normal-normal-normal-*-13-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1 (#x04)

Character code properties: customize what to show
  name: LATIN SMALL LETTER N
  general-category: Ll (Letter, Lowercase)
  decomposition: (110) ('n')

There are text properties here:
  face                 org-quote
  font-lock-fontified  t
  font-lock-multiline  t
  fontified            t
  line-prefix          [Show]
  org-emphasis         t
  wrap-prefix          [Show]
```

Comment: What's your Org mode version? I cannot reproduce it with Org mode version 9.4.4 (release_9.4.4-184-gedda21). You *are* talking about markup, correct? `Lorem /ipsum/ ...`

Comment: 9.0.5… maybe this is my problem? Yes, markup

Comment: I can't reproduce it with 9.0.5 either - I suspect it is caused by something in your init file. Try starting emacs with `emacs -q`: if that resolves the problem, then your init file is responsible somehow. Can you also do `C-u C-x =` on a character that should be italic and tell us what face that reports? Please edit the question and add all this information.

Comment: @NickD I have added the output of ´C-u C-x =´ but could not get Emacs to start without the init file in my terminal (on Mac OS), probably because of something with the path, will look into that.

Comment: Check the value of `org-fontify-quote-and-verse-block`, which is `nil` by default, meaning those blocks should be fontified like regular org.

Comment: @BrianCully Ah! Thanks, that did it. I hade misinterpreted the option to mean the opposite (that it needed to be non-nil). Would you like to add this as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The answer version of my comment on the question.]

Check the value of `org-fontify-quote-and-verse-block`, which is nil by default, meaning those blocks should be fontified like regular org.

Comment: In my Emacs 27.2 (with Org 9.4.4), the variable is called `org-fontify-quote-and-verse-blocks` (plural).